# frequent disconect wifi on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, internet

Recently days, my laptop frequent disconect wifi about 5 minute/onece. I tried research and used many ways to resolve it but nothing happened:

Updated my kernel from 5.15 to 5.19 and 6.09

Disabled IPv6

Tried disable power save for Wifi

My OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64bit

Machine: MSI-Modern-15-A5M

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U

GNOME: 42.5

Comment: I just updated the kernel to version 5.17 and seems everything is ok, wifi works well until now, I will update the new status if having any problem with wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, My laptop works well with kernel 5.17